# Magento 2 - Cannot reindex Catalog rule product and catalog product rule

Tags: magento2, reindex, migration, indexer

I get the following error when I try to reindex

[image: error]

when I check index status...

```
Design Config Grid:                                Ready
Customer Grid:                                     Ready
Category Products:                                 Ready
Product Categories:                                Ready
Product Price:                                     Ready
Product EAV:                                       Ready
Stock:                                             Ready
Catalog Rule Product:                              Reindex required
Catalog Product Rule:                              Reindex required
Catalog Search:                                    Ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Solution, create a catalog rule in Marketing -> Catalog Price Rule, this enter one row in tables on database.
That error happen when you migrate magento, some tables still empty.